# Can you download an Azure Blob using Virtual Machine Identity Access Token through PowerShell without using Access Keys

Tags: azure, powershell, api, blob, amazon-iam

I'm setting up a VM to do some bootstrapping on creation.
Part of this is to download a blob from an azure storage account to the VM.
These are all in the same subscription, resource group, etc.

I can do it this way fine:

```
function Get-BlobUsingVMIdentity 
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $containerName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $blobName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $outputFolder
    )

    write-host "Defining package information"
        mkdir $outputFolder -force

    write-host "Getting Instance meta data"
        $instanceInfo = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance/?api-version=2018-02-01' `
            -Headers @{Metadata="true"} `
            | select -expand content `
            | convertfrom-json `
            | select -expand compute

        $storageAccountName = "$($instanceInfo.resourceGroupName.replace('-rg',''))sa" # This is custom since we know our naming schema
        $resourceGroupName = $($instanceInfo.resourceGroupName)
        $subscriptionId = $($instanceInfo.subscriptionId)

    write-host "Got storageAccountName [$storageAccountName], resourceGroupName [$resourceGroupName], subscriptionId [$subscriptionId]"

    write-host "Getting VM Instance Access Token"
        $response = Invoke-WebRequest  -UseBasicParsing -Uri 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2F' `
            -Headers @{Metadata = "true" }

        $content = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
        $access_token = $content.access_token

    write-host "Getting SAS Token From Storage Account"
        $params = @{canonicalizedResource = "/blob/$($storageAccountName)/$($containerName)"; signedResource = "c"; signedPermission = "rcw"; signedProtocol = "https"; signedExpiry = "2031-09-23T00:00:00Z" }
        $jsonParams = $params | ConvertTo-Json

        $sasResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$($subscriptionId)/resourceGroups/$($resourceGroupName)/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/$($storageAccountName)/listServiceSas/?api-version=2017-06-01" `
            -Method POST `
            -Body $jsonParams `
            -Headers @{Authorization="Bearer $access_token"}

        $sasContent = $sasResponse.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
        $sasCred = $sasContent.serviceSasToken

    write-host "Manually download blob"
        $params = @{signedResource = "c"; signedPermission = "rcw"; signedProtocol = "https"; signedExpiry = "2031-09-23T00:00:00Z" }
        $jsonParams = $params | ConvertTo-Json

        $sasResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://$($storageAccountName).blob.core.windows.net/$($containerName)/$($blobName)?api-version=2017-06-01" `
            -Method POST `
            -Body $jsonParams `
            -Headers @{Authorization="Bearer $access_token"}

        $sasContent = $sasResponse.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
        $sasCred = $sasContent.serviceSasToken

    write-host "Setting up storage context"
        $ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -SasToken $sasCred

    write-host "Downloading package"
        Get-AzStorageBlobContent `
            -Blob $blobName `
            -Container $containerName `
            -Destination $outputFolder `
            -Context $ctx `
            -Force
}
```

This works fine, except I have to grant full/write access to the identity in order for it to use the access key.

Is there a similar approach that would allow read only access to the blob?
My goals are:
1. No credentials stored anywhere
2. Download blob to VM from azure storage
3. No statically defined variables (ex: subscriptionid)
4. Read only access to the blob/storage account.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Found a much easier way to do it!
The key was to use:

`Connect-AzAccount -identity`

This auto logs in a the identity and allows you to interact through AZ module instead of trying to hack API calls together.

You only need [Storage Blob Data Reader] assigned to the container to pull this off.

Working example looks like this:

```
function Get-BlobUsingVMIdentity
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $containerName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $blobName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $outputFolder
    )

    write-host "Get instance info"
        $instanceInfo = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance/?api-version=2018-02-01' `
                -Headers @{Metadata="true"} `
                | select -expand content `
                | convertfrom-json `
                | select -expand compute

        $storageAccountName = "$($instanceInfo.resourceGroupName.replace('-rg',''))sa" # This is custom since we know our naming schema

    write-host "Clear existing identies to keep cache fresh"
        Clear-AzContext -force

    write-host "Authenticate using identity"
        $account = Connect-AzAccount -identity
        if(-not $account.Context.Subscription.Id)
        {
            write-error "Failed to authenticate with identity. Ensure VM has identity enabled and is assigned the correct IAM roles"
            return
        }

    write-host "Get storage context"
        $ctx = New-AZStorageContext  -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName

    write-host "Getting blob"
        Get-AzStorageBlobContent `
            -Blob $blobName `
            -Container $containerName `
            -Destination $outputFolder `
            -Context $ctx `
            -Force
}


Get-BlobUsingVMIdentity `
        -containerName "deploy" `
        -blobName "deploy.zip" `
        -outputFolder "c:\deploy\"
```

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding, you want to use Azure VM MSI to access Azure storage. If so, please refer to the following steps:

1. Enable a system-assigned managed identity on a VM

```
Connect-AzAccount
$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Name myVM
Update-AzVM -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -VM $vm -AssignIdentity:$SystemAssigned
```

2. Grant your VM access to an Azure Storage container

```
Connect-AzAccount
$spID = (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName myRG -Name myVM).identity.principalid
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $spID -RoleDefinitionName "Storage Blob Data Reader" -Scope "/subscriptions/<mySubscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<myResourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<myStorageAcct>/blobServices/default/containers/<container-name>"
```

3. access blob

```
# get AD access token
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2F' `
                              -Headers @{Metadata="true"}
$content =$response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$access_token = $content.access_token

# call Azure blob rest api
$url="https://<myaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<mycontainer>/<myblob>"
$RequestHeader = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$RequestHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $access_token")
$RequestHeader.Add("x-ms-version", "2019-02-02")

$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $RequestHeader
$result.content
```

---

## Update

According to my test, when we get token to access Azure blob, we need to change resouce as https://storage.azure.com/

```
# get AD access token
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://storage.azure.com/' `
                              -Headers @{Metadata="true"}
$content =$response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$access_token = $content.access_token

# call Azure blob rest api
$url="https://<myaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<mycontainer>/<myblob>"
$RequestHeader = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$RequestHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $access_token")
$RequestHeader.Add("x-ms-version", "2019-02-02")

$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $RequestHeader
$result.content
```

[image]

Comment: I think i tried this approach but couldn't seem to get past this error:


`$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $RequestHeader
Invoke-WebRequest : `

`AuthenticationFailedServer failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:6958fdc0-501e-002a-6abf-cb4eab000000
Time:2020-01-15T16:19:13.9105170ZAudience validation failed. Audience did not match.`

Comment: @EricLongstreet  Sorry. I made a mistake. We should change the resource as https://storage.azure.com/ when we get token. For more details, please refer to my update

Comment: Thanks for the update/test. I found the Azure API calls to be very clumsy sadly. I posted my answer above which i think is a cleaner approach and allows you to stay in the powershell az module and avoid stitching everything together.

Comment: I tested your code and it worked as well! Thanks for the feedback.